# Array and pointer appeared as a function parameter and just as a declaration

Tags: c++, arrays

I was a bit confused by the fact that the functions differ in presence/absence `cv`-qualifiers are equiavalent `N4296::13.1/3.4 [over.load]`:

> Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence of
>   const and/or volatile are equivalent.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int){ }

void foo(const int){ } //error: redifinition

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c33a21da2084e484)**

Now, let me provide an example with member-functions.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(){ }
    void foo(){ std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl; }
    void foo() const{ std::cout << "foo() const" << std::endl; }
};

A aa;
const A a;
int main(){ aa.foo(); a.foo(); }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34fc633fe2782124)**

`N4296::13.3.1/2 [over.match.funcs]`

> member function is considered to have an extra parameter, called the
>   implicit object parameter, which represents the object for which the
>   member function has been called

So, the member function declarations are different only in presence of the `const`-qualifier, but they are still overloadable. Doesn't it contradict to the quote from `N4296::13.1/3.4 [over.load]` I provided before?

Comment: There is huge difference.Const member function means you can't modify data in that function.

Comment: No, the "constness" of a member function is part of the function signature.

Comment: Why do you think the C++ rules are applicable to the things on asm level / in the compiler (implicit object pointer)?

Comment: The difference between `A*` and `const A*` is very different from the difference between `int` and `const int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quoted passage (disclaimer: I haven't checked the quote or attribution, but anyway, this property of C++) is about top level `const` (and `volatile`) for a formal argument.

For example,

```
void foo( const int x );
```

is equivalent to

```
void foo( int x );
```

with respect to calling, checking its type, and so on. This is because there is no way it can matter to a caller whether a formal argument is `const` or not. That `const`-ness is only a restriction on what the function itself can do, not what callers can do.

And so for `void foo( int )` you can provide an implementation with `const`:

```
void foo( const int x ) { cout << x << endl; }
```

It implements `void foo( int )` because they're equivalent.

With a `const` member function you're instead saying that the referent for `this` is `const`. That's not a top level `const`. Adding that `const` is roughly equivalent to changing

```
void bar( int* p );
```

into

```
void bar( const int* p );
```

which are two different functions.

Comment: Did you mean the implicit argument parameter has a pointer to type?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Essentially, yes, in the sense that we can imagine a rewrite of dot notation calls to calls with the implicit argument present as an explicit first argument. To make that view work one would have to consider that `this` is formally an rvalue. But essentially.

Answer (score 0):

There is huge difference.Const member function means you can't modify data in that function.**It includes in function signature** and thats how compiler differentiates.Also accroding to [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-member-fns.html)

> The trailing const on foo() member function means that the
>   abstract (client-visible) state of the object isn't going to change.
>   This is slightly different from promising that the "raw bits" of the
>   object's struct aren't going to change. C++ compilers aren't allowed
>   to take the "bitwise" interpretation unless they can solve the
>   aliasing problem, which normally can't be solved (i.e., a non-const
>   alias could exist which could modify the state of the object).

```
    #include <iostream>

    struct A
    {
        A(){var=0; }
        void foo(){ std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl; }
        void foo() const{ std::cout << "foo() const" << std::endl;var=5; } //this will generate error

        private:
        int var;
    };



A aa;
const A a;
int main(){ aa.foo(); a.foo(); }
```

we will get **error: read-only variable is not assignable**

see this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/